# Keyboard shortcut for changing windows in Octave

Tags: octave

Is there any way to change from, for example, editor to command windows, or current folder etc in Octave? In Matlab, this can be done through the "Next tool", that is "Go to the next workflow step", which I normally set to be "Ctrl+Tab". This means, I just need to repeatedly hit the Ctrl+Tab buttons until I get to the window that I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see all available shortcuts or set your own from the preferences (Edit -> Preferences -> Shortcuts).

There is no 'rotating' shortcut, but you can set shortcuts to go to the particular window you want directly. The default shortcuts are:

```
Ctrl + 0 : Command Window
Ctrl + 1 : Command History
Ctrl + 2 : File Browser
Ctrl + 3 : Workspace
Ctrl + 4 : Editor
Ctrl + 5 : Documentation
Ctrl + 6 : Variable Editor
```

Similarly, adding shift to the above toggles their visibility on or off.

More importantly, if the reason you need tabbing is because you keep having to switch from the console to the editor, note that you can actually drag the editor from its titlebar and place it separately alongside the editor so that the two appear side-by-side.

Comment: Thanks very much @Tasos Papastylianou . Really appreciate your answer.. Unfortunately, I can't vote for your answer since I have less than 15 reputation.

Comment: No worries. Enjoy octave. Having said that you can accept it by clicking the tick if you think it is adequately answers your question.